# Spring gateway application unable to find custom filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, spring-cloud, gateway

I'm trying to add a Gateway filter, but for some reason the application can't seem to find the custom filter that I created. This is the error that I get.

[image]

My code looks like this:

**Application.yml**

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: securityService
          uri: http://localhost:8083
          predicates:
            - Method=POST
            - Path=/auth/**
          filters:
            - MyGatewayFilterFactory
```

**MyGatewayFilterFactory**

```
package com.gateway.cloudstreamproducerrabbitmq;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class MyGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<MyGatewayFilterFactory.Config>  {

    public MyGatewayFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }


    private boolean isAuthorizationValid(String authorizationHeader) {
        boolean isValid = true;

        // Logic for checking the value
        return isValid;
    }

    private Mono<Void> onError(ServerWebExchange exchange, String err, HttpStatus httpStatus)  {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(httpStatus);

        return response.setComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

            System.out.println("Test");

            if (!request.getHeaders().containsKey("Authorization")) {
                return this.onError(exchange, "No Authorization header", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            };

            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeaders().get("Authorization").get(0);

            if (!this.isAuthorizationValid(authorizationHeader)) {
                return this.onError(exchange, "Invalid Authorization header", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

            ServerHttpRequest modifiedRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().
                    header("secret", "RANDOMRANDOMRANDOM").
                    build();


            return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(modifiedRequest).build());
        };
    }

    public static class Config {
        // Put the configuration properties
    }
}
```

If I forgot to provide some information, let me know. I'll update this post.

I haven't worked with filters before so i'm still new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem just by creating a @Bean with the new custom class inside the main App class, as described in [this tutorial](https://programmer.help/blogs/spring-cloud-2.x-version-gateway-custom-filter-tutorial.html).

```
@Bean
public CustomFilter customFilter() {
    return new CustomFilter();
}
```